# Why is my Python package being imported as a "namespace" module, and how can I import modules correctly?

Tags: python, namespaces, python-import, python-module

I have two packages I am trying to play with in an IPython console. The file structures for both packages, `ibllib` and `ecephys_spike_sorting` is shown below.

[image: ibllib file directory structure]

[image: ecephys_spike_sorting file directory structure]

`ibllib` imports fine and as I expect, but I am confused as to why `ecephys_spike_sorting` gets imported as a namespace module, and why I can't access modules within it. (Below is a screenshot of me trying to play with both packages in an IPython console). I would appreciate any help in understanding how to import `ecephys_spike_sorting` as I have imported `ibllib`, and generally understanding namespace modules and why I would ever want to use a namespace module (e.g., is there ever a reason I would want `ecephys_spike_sorting` imported as is shown here?)

[image: importing both packages in ipython console]

Comment: Does this behaviour persist if you restart the console?

Comment: seems to be expected behaviour.

try 
`import ecephys_spike_sorting.modules.quality_metrics.metrics`

if you wanted you could add to `__init__.py` file in the ecephys_spike_sorting directory
`from . import modules`

and in the `__init__.py` file of the modules directory

`from . import automerging` and `from . import quality_metrics`

If you want further help from me, then please post also a text version of your messages. Copy paste from screen shots is not possible and I do not like to retype pieces of your code.

look at the contents of the `__init_.py` to understand better

Comment: "If you wanted you could add to `__init__.py` file in the ecephys_spike_sorting directory `from . import modules` and in the `__init__.py` file of the modules directory `from . import automerging` and `from . import quality_metrics`" 
                                                                                                             @gelonida yes, the above worked. could you explain to me why it's necessary?

Comment: Honestly speaking. 
I'm not sure I can explain much better than the official documentation.

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages

explains the python logic of packages.

The main point is. packages / name spaces are there to organizes modules in a logical way, but they do not import themselves recursively.

`__init__.py` is always imported / executed and can do some of the magic, that you are looking for.

On the other hand normally you might want to let a user decide what he really wants to import instead of importing everything in one go.

Comment: copied from the doc:
The `__init__.py` files are required to make Python treat directories containing the file as packages. This prevents directories with a common name, such as string, unintentionally hiding valid modules that occur later on the module search path. In the simplest case, `__init__.py` can just be an empty file, but it can also execute initialization code for the package or set the` __all__` variable, described later.